# How do I get rid of the big blue bar at the top of Google?

Tags: google-chrome, google

How do I get rid of this big blue bar at the top of Google:

[image: http://cl.ly/3O12021D3D2F2j1b3x2g]

It is really annoying!

I am running Google Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: I'd suggest clicking there.

Comment: also, you can change the black bar back to the old one too. http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/105723

Comment: The Google interface has changed a couple of times since this was asked. This will help no future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: I've only tested this on Windows but I'm assuming it should be the same on the Mac.**

It's possible to do this with AdBlock Plus. Get it by going to http://adblockplus.org/en/ and clicking the big green button. Be sure to click the little **Continue** button that appears at the bottom to confirm that you want to install it.

Once installed there should be a red stop icon in the address bar. Right-click the icon and choose **Options**, then go to the tab called **Add your own filters**. Enter the following:

```
###mgmhppd
```

This tells AdBlock to remove the element with an ID of 'mgmhppd' (the blue bar). Click **Add filter** to confirm.

If you find AdBlock interferes with any other sites you can disable it for that site by left-clicking the icon and unticking **Enable for this site**.

Comment: They have changed it now: `###gbprw`

Comment: It seems they will probably change it periodically.

Answer (score -1):

OK, not my idea, found on another forum, tried it and it worked!

Go to the Start menu, type <kbd>regedit</kbd>, right click on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` choose *Find* and type in <kbd>google</kbd>. You will see a *Google* folder, delete this and close.

The first time you open browser you may see it once, click on *No thanks*  and that should be it.   Please note, this is on Windows 7, but should work on others!

Comment: This sounds strange. Could you add a link to the forum where you found this?

Answer (score -3):

I had the Get to Google faster  Update your default search engine. Sure   No thanks 
Don't click on sure or no thanks       Click on Tools,  Compatibility view settings,     ADD this website, Google. com    then Close       This got rid of the blue bar for me﻿

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense…